# html anchor text is appearing toward the top?

Tags: html, css

Trying to clone the template on the far left for practice from this dribbble:

https://dribbble.com/shots/2262761-Mobile-Blog-App-Interface/attachments/424147

Here is my code pen so far:

https://codepen.io/TheKyleDev/project/editor/ZWbLbw

```
.hero a {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  font-size: 0.65em;
  padding: 8px 18px;
}
```

For some reason the button link is acting weird. The text is appearing closer to the top despite having even padding top and bottom. Can somebody explain this to me?

Comment: Do you mean the "travel" button? What exactly do you mean by "*The text is appearing closer to the top despite having even padding top and bottom*" - do you mean that the text isn't vertically aligned within the button? It looks perfectly fine for me in  Chrome 61.0

Comment: That *design* tag is not appropriate here. Please care to read tag descriptions. It just appears when you hover a tag, easy right!

Comment: yes @FluffyKitten the travel text looks closer to the top of the button. I counted the pixels between the bottom and top, the bottom is 13 pixels of space and the top has 11 pixels. I'm guessing it might be the font or something?

Comment: @KyleDev Yes it is a tiny bit closer to the top (I thought you were having issues with no padding at the top for example). But as you suspect, that is down to the font. Different fonts can have different spacing for ascents, descents etc, and if you set the padding to 0 on the button, you'll see the text has a little extra space at the bottom. On the plus side, I doubt anyone would really notice - we're used to looking at different fonts and spacing. But if if wanted you could always adjust the padding to add 1px more to the top.